# create a scoring matrix from two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I am trying to compare sets of variables(`X`) that are stored in two dataframes (`foo`, `bar`).  Each `X` is a unique independent variable that has up to 10 values of `Y` associated with it. I would like to compare every foo.X with every bar.X by comparing the number of `Y` values they have in common - so the output could be a matrix with axes of foo.x by bar.x in length.

this simple example of foo and bar would want to return a 2x2 matrix comparing a,b with c,d:

```
foo <- data.frame(x= c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), y=c('ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'fx', 'fy'))
bar <- data.frame(x= c('c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'), y=c('ab', 'xy', 'xz', 'xy', 'fx', 'xz'))
```

---

EDIT:

---

I've left the following code for other newbies to learn from (for loops are effectvie but probably very suboptimal), but the two solutions below are effective. In particular Ramnath's use of data.table is very effective when dealing with very large dataframes.

store the dataframes as lists where the values of y are stored using the `stack` function

```
foo.list <- dlply(foo, .(x), function(x) stack(x, select = y))
bar.list <- dlply(bar, .(x),function(x)  stack(x, select = y))
```

write a function for comparing membership in the two stacked lists

```
comparelists <- function(list1, list2) {
  for (i in list1){ 
    for (j in list2){
      count <- 0
      if (i[[1]] %in% j[[1]]) count <- count + 1
    }
  }
  return count
  }
```

write an output matrix

```
output.matrix <- matrix(1:length(foo.list), 1:length(bar.list))
for (i in foo.list){
  for (j in bar.list){
    output.matrix[i,j] <- comparelists(i,j)

    }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach using `merge`

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- merge(foo, bar, by = 'y')
dcast(df1, x.x ~ x.y, length)

  x.x c d
1   a 1 0
2   b 0 1
```

EDIT. The merge can be faster using `data.table`. Here is the code

```
foo_dt <- data.table(foo, key = 'y')
bar_dt <- data.table(bar, key = 'y')
df1 <- bar_dt[foo_dt, nomatch = 0]
```

Comment: thanks @ramnath  - this is indeed a very elegant and easy solution. Unfortunately this guy also crashes my computer when I apply it to the entire dataset. I think i am going to to return to my pre-R strategy of using python for processing my data (i iterate through the data and write the results to a file so the computer doesn't flip out) and then use R for its graphing capabilites.

Comment: how big are `foo` and `bar` and how many levels do they contain?

Comment: check my edit. it uses `data.table` to do the `merge` and hence is very efficient. can you check if this works for you? i am trying to figure out an efficient way to `cast` the data, if that step is the bottleneck.

Comment: wow. using datatable  is WAY faster. My `foo` and `bar` are about 55k and 1.5M in length. I haven't tried casting on the full length dataframe yet since I think there may be something  funny in the way the dables are joining.

Comment: data.table is AWESOME! dcast of the resulting table is pretty quick and now I can focus on casting/splitting/subsetting to my heart's content. Thank you for taking the time to show me this method. I am always impressed by the Stack Overflow community!

Comment: whenever i hit a speed related road-block, i turn to `data.table`. glad that it worked.

Comment: @zach -- Just be aware that, as currently presented, Ramnath's approach and my own give different answers. For groups in one data.frame that share no elements with any of the groups in the other data.frame, Ramnath's method will drop them from the output, whereas mine will keep them as a row of `0`'s. To see what I mean, after creating `foo` and `bar`, do `bar[5,2] <- "xy"`, and then analyze the data using our two functions.  Ramnath's approach is still the way to go, but you may need to do some post processing of its results if you want to keep rows with all 0s in your results...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien @Ramnath Thank you both. There are a few quirks about data.table that I don't yet understand, for instance: despite having only 10 values of `Y`, the dcast(df1,x.x~x.y, length) results values between 1-20. Zeros are dropped but scores are also changed. I think this is result of using the 'y' value as a key and that the joins are longer for abundant `y` values than for less abundant `y' values (why?) and this is probably correctable by indexing along `y` and `x` for one of the tables. I want to learn but may temporarily retreat to trusty python so i can continue downstream analysis

Comment: @zach -- Sounds like a plan.  If you do want to learn about `data.table` in the future, the examples in the help file (`?data.table`) make a great tutorial. Spending 30-60 minutes to work through them line by line will get you much of the way to understanding the syntax of the language.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien. I think I will work through the tutorial since ideally i'd like to do everything R, and the speed of data.table is impressive. Also I am still not sure why I get the duplicates but they can be eliminated using df1 <- df1[!duplicated(df1)] before casting. So for some reason the the join step produced up to 13 duplicated rows. Hmmm......

Answer (score 4):

There must be a hundred ways to do this; here is one that feels relatively straightforward to me:

```
library(reshape2)
foo <- data.frame(x = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), 
                  y = c('ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'fx', 'fy'))
bar <- data.frame(x = c('c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'), 
                  y = c('ab', 'xy', 'xz', 'xy', 'fx', 'xz'))

# Create a function that counts the number of common elements in two groups
nShared <- function(A, B) {
    length(intersect(with(foo, y[x==A]), with(bar, y[x==B])))
}

# Enumerate all combinations of groups in foo and bar
(combos <- expand.grid(foo.x=unique(foo$x), bar.x=unique(bar$x)))
#   foo.x bar.x
# 1     a     c
# 2     b     c
# 3     a     d
# 4     b     d

# Find number of elements in common among all pairs of groups
combos$n <- mapply(nShared, A=combos$foo.x, B=combos$bar.x)

# Reshape results into matrix form
dcast(combos, foo.x ~ bar.x)
#   foo.x c d
# 1     a 1 0
# 2     b 0 1
```

Comment: nice!  I see you expand to a large grid, count the overlaps and then recast. Elegant. But what if foo and bar are actually thousands of members long? Would you change your method?

Comment: I wouldn't change it unless the calculation was really slowing down. But I think this should scale pretty well to larger data sets.

Comment: thanks Josh.  i'm new enough in R not to have used intersect, expand.grid, dcast or mapply - so in addition to being a quick answer this is a real help!

Comment: after the combos <- expand() line i do not get the output you show. I get: [1] bar.x
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names) . I face a similar problem when using my true dataset.

Comment: The columns of your data.frames were probably of class `character` rather than `factor`, and so `levels()` didn't work, with them.  I've edited the answer, replacing `levels()` with `unique()`. It should now should work with both character and factor columns.

Comment: comparing two datasets of about 500 and 15k, the resulting length of `combos` is  ~ 6 million. This is causing my computer to churn at the `combos$n` step. Do you have any suggestions for how to get this to work? maybe change 'mapply' to a 'csv.write' step so that I am writing to a file?