# mapply within ddply

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

note: this is a direct follow up to this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749589/create-a-scoring-matrix-from-two-dataframes)

---

I have very long dataframe consisting of two columns that I am using as arguments for a function that will find the value of a third column using mapply as so:

```
df$3rd <- mapply(myfunction, A=df$1st, B=df$2nd)
```

where `myfunction` has arguments A and B. While this works great for small datasets, it stalls for large datasets so I was thinking a good way to approach the problem would be to apply this function using `ddply`. I don't know if `ddply` is the best approach for this problem but I am also having some trouble with syntax. So suggestions for either would be appreciated.

This is what I am trying:

```
> df$3rd <- ddply(df, .(1st), function(x) x$3rd <-
> mapply(myfunction, A=x$1st, B=df$second))
```

and this is the error I am getting:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "n", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 112 rows, data has 16
```

EDIT:

---

---

In light of the answer and comments I I am posting a small reproducible example below - it is one of the answers from the previous question. However as the commenters below note, ddply is probably not the way to go. I am trying Ramnath's solution right now.

```
library(reshape2)
foo <- data.frame(x = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'), 
                  y = c('ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'fx', 'fy'))
bar <- data.frame(x = c('c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'), 
                  y = c('ab', 'xy', 'xz', 'xy', 'fx', 'xz'))

nShared <- function(A, B) {
    length(intersect(with(foo, y[x==A]), with(bar, y[x==B])))
}

# Enumerate all combinations of groups in foo and bar
(combos <- expand.grid(foo.x=unique(foo$x), bar.x=unique(bar$x)))

# Find number of elements in common among all pairs of groups
combos$n <- mapply(nShared, A=combos$foo.x, B=combos$bar.x)

# Reshape results into matrix form
dcast(combos, foo.x ~ bar.x)
#   foo.x c d
# 1     a 1 0
# 2     b 0 1
```

Comment: Generally speaking, plyr functions are there for convenience (handy syntax), apply family of functions usually does better of when time is of concern. Care to provide a small reproducible example?

Comment: @zach. check out my solution to your earlier question. it does away with the need to use `mapply` and `expand.grid`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ddply` isn't what you're after here, `ddply(df,.(1st), FUNCTION)` is more like:

```
for each val in unique(df$1st)
    outdf[nrow(outdf)+1,] = FUNCTION( df[df$1st==val] )
```

That is, it makes `outdf` consisting of `FUNCTION` applied to subsets of `df` determined by column `1st`.

In any case, I think your error might be because you have `df` instead of `x` in `function(x) x$3rd<-mapply(myfunction,A=x$1st, B=df$second)` (the `B` argument)? Although it is hard to tell without a working example.

What exactly does `myfunction` do? I think your best bet is to *vectorise* `myfunction` so that you can just do `df$third <- myfunction( A=df$first, B=df$second )`.

For example, if `myfunction <- function(A,B) { A+B }`, instead of doing `mapply(myfunction,df$first,df$second)` you could equivalently do `myfunction(df$first,df$second)` and not even need mapply at all.

Comment: thanks @mathematical.coffee.  i think you're right  - both in that ddply will not yield performance gains and AND that it would be a good idea to vectorize my function. However, my function serves as lookup for values in two other dataframes - see above and previous question- so vectorization won't be possible. I think I will go back to my pre-R strategy which was to process my data in python and use R for analysis of the resulting table.

Comment: @Zach. In the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749589/create-a-scoring-matrix-from-two-dataframes)'s comments you found [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/). Does it work for this one too?

Comment: @MatthewDowle. It might work for this case but data.table obviates the  need for it. This question was aimed to clarify a problem encountered with one of the solutions of the previous question. Ramnath's data.table solution is fast enough and less memory intensive so I can use his solution directly and not worry about this question. If you are wondering whether multiple arguments can be passed to data.table I not sure but you can definitely pass it consecutive functions. Also - data.table behaves differently than data.frame so check your results carefully until you're sure you've got it right.